# CKEditor deleting <span> in Django

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'm having a problem with CKeditor (with ckeditor_uploader) in Django, I looked everywhere, found a lot of answers but none of those worked.

The solutions I found was inserting one of those to the config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.autoParagraph = false;
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'span(*)';
};

CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.span = 0;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['span'] = false;
```

[image: Inserting span tag]

Everytime I click out of source and go back, or save and go back, the span tag is gone:
[image]

Also, this is what I have in my settings.py:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'moono',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': [
                'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': [
                'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': [
                'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
            {'name': 'forms',
             'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                       'HiddenField']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': [
                'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
            {'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
            '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
                'Preview',
                'Maximize',

            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', 
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
            'wysiwygarea',
            'justify,liststyle,indent',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath'
        ]),
        "removePlugins": "stylesheetparser",
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Or I'm inputing the configurations in the wrong place? (my ckeditor folder is inside static, path (static/ckeditor/ckeditor/config.js).

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I was passing allowedContent = true; at the wrogn place, the correct place is at settings.py, under CKEDITOR_CONFIGS.